# SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 51836

Tags: javascript, json, express, encode, filepond

I am trying to save multiple images using filepond library. Saving a single image works perfectly and it is saved and rendered when I make a GET request.
Saving multiple(or even two) images on the other hand throws the error above. Here is my code

`HTML`

```
<input multiple type="file" id="imageAnswer" name="imageAnswer" class="filepond">
```

```
router.post('/', async (req,res) =>{

    let newCPA = new CPASchema({
        level:req.body.level,
        year:req.body.year,
        unitCode:req.body.unitCode,
        unitName:req.body.unitName,
        answer:req.body.answer,

    })
    saveImageAnswer(newCPA, req.body.imageAnswer)

    try {
        const cpa = await newCPA.save()
        .then(()=> res.redirect('/'))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});

function saveImageAnswer(newCPA, coverEncoded){

    if (coverEncoded == '') return;

    const img =  JSON.parse(coverEncoded);
    if(img != null &&  imageMimeTypes.includes(img.type)){
        newCPA.imageAnswer = new Buffer.from(img.data, 'base64');
        newCPA.imageAnswerType = img.type;
    }
    
}
```

HERE`S MY SCHEMA

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const marked = require('marked'); //Converts markdown to HTML
const createDomPurify = require('dompurify'); //Sanitizes our HTML
const {JSDOM} = require('jsdom');
const dompurify = createDomPurify( new JSDOM().window);

const CPASchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    level:{
        type:String,
        enum:['Foundation', 'Intermediate', 'Advanced']
    },
    year: {
        type:Number
    },
    unitCode: {
        type: String
    },
    unitName:{
        type:String
    },
    question:{
        type: String
    },
    answer:{
        type:String
    },
    imageAnswer:{
        type: Buffer,

    },
    imageAnswerType:{
        type: String,
    },
    sanitizedQSTN:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sanitizedANSWER:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt:{
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

CPASchema.pre('validate', async function(next){

    console.log('JUST BEFORE SANITIZING FOR CPA')
    if(this.question) {
        this.sanitizedQSTN = await dompurify.sanitize(marked.parse(this.question))
    }


    if(this.answer) {
        this.sanitizedANSWER = await dompurify.sanitize(marked.parse(this.answer))
    }
    next()
});



CPASchema.virtual('coverImagePath').get( function(){
    if(this.imageAnswer != null && this.imageAnswerType != null) {
        return `data:${this.imageAnswerType};charset=utf-8;base64,${this.imageAnswer.toString('base64')}`
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('CPASchema', CPASchema);
```

I have reduced the file sizes but it keeps telling the `,` is the problem and I think it is only because there`re multiple files and the code does not seem to have any prolem(IMO). Please direct me on how I can save multiple files using filePond.

Comment: Please also add a stacktrace to your question

Comment: @user2488801batman I`m sorry, what ia a stacktrace and how do I add it?